# Could not load class when executed with -cp option

Tags: java, jar, classpath, apache-pig

Java not able to find the class file when executed with -cp option as below

```
javac -cp ~/softwares/pig-0.12.0/pig-0.12.0.jar PR.java
```

Compilation is successful. However when I run the above generated class I am getting error

```
java -cp ~/softwares/pig-0.12.0/pig-0.12.0.jar PR
 Error: Could not find or load main class PR
```

If I remove the -cp I am getting below error which is expected

```
 java PR
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pig/PigServer
    at PR.runPigScript(PR.java:9)
    at PR.main(PR.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pig.PigServer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 2 more
```

Could you please let me what might be reasons for failure is Step-2(Could not find or load main class) . Below is the code of PR.java

```
  import org.apache.pig.ExecType;
  import org.apache.pig.PigServer;
  import org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException;

 public class PR {

    public void runPigScript(){
            try {
                    PigServer  pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.LOCAL);
                    pigServer.registerScript("RP.pig");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

  public static void main(String[] args){
      PR pr = new PR();
     pr.runPigScript();
  }

}
```

From https://wiki.apache.org/pig/EmbeddedPig

To run your program, you need to first compile it by using the following command:

```
   javac -cp <path>pig.jar WordCount.java
```

If the compilation is successful, you can then run your program:

```
   java -cp <path>pig.jar WordCount
```

Comment: Do you have a main method in your PR class?

Comment: Yes , I have main method in PR class . When I run without -cp option , class is executed and getting expected exception

Comment: Is your code calling `org/apache/pig/PigServer` directly?  Does this class exist in the jar file?

Comment: Your class named PR has no package, is it true?

Comment: Yes , I have removed the package to make it default

Comment: Show your code, especially main method like people ask you

Comment: @Java1 , Yes , mentioned class exists in the jar file . The problem is java not able to load the PR class

Comment: it is loading the PR class, as it is telling you which line of PR class is causing the trouble.

Comment: @Java1 When I removed -cp option the class is loading. But I have to add the Pig jar in classpath to execute without errors an if I do that the java is not able to load/find PR class

Comment: What errors do you get when not using `-cp`?

Comment: See my answer, you need to add current directory to your classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
java -cp ~/softwares/pig-0.12.0/pig-0.12.0.jar;. PR
```

The problem is that you need to load your compiled PR class as well. So your classpath needs to have both dependencies and your compiled output. Add current directory to the classpath.

Comment: Wanted to post the same. Yes, it should do the job!

Comment: I was blind not to see it for the first time :-)