# Could not load class when executed with -cp option of `'hadoop classpath`

Tags: java, hadoop, classpath

my question is very close to this one, which is already answered. 
[Could not load class when executed with -cp option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077064/could-not-load-class-when-executed-with-cp-option)

However, the situation is slightly different

```
$ javac -cp `hadoop classpath` GrabHDFSBlockInfo.java 
$ java -cp `hadoop classpath` GrabHDFSBlockInfo 
 Error: Could not find or load main class GrabHDFSBlockInfo
$ ls GrabHDFSBlockInfo*
 GrabHDFSBlockInfo.class  GrabHDFSBlockInfo.java
```

so I'd like to use the shortcut of `hadoop classpath` in this case.

many thanks for your help

Demai

---

edit: thanks for everyone's help. Since hadoop classpath doesn't change much on my cluster. I eventually change my .bashrc, by setup a var with expanded classpath padding ':.' then, just use $ java -cp $classpath  GrabHDFSBlockInfo

Comment: Is your class in a package?

Comment: no. it is just a simple client code. I compiled it to .class into the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

One of the known problems of `hadoop classpath` is that it contains wildcards. As a result of that, the hadoop libraries cannot be loaded properly. As a workaround, try expanding the wildcards, replacing them with sequences of  jars located there. It will most probably help.

A little zsh script for a similar purpose (though I simply updated existing CLASSPATH there):

```
classpath=`hadoop classpath | tr ':' ' ' | sort | uniq`
for file in ${=~classpath}(N)
do
  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$file
done
```